# django 1.4 timezone.now() vs datetime.datetime.now()

Tags: django, timezone

I'm a bit confused by the daylight savings handling

settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
USE_TZ = True
```

in the django shell:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> import datetime
>>> print timezone.now()
2012-05-28 11:19:42.897000+00:00
>>> print timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(),timezone.get_default_timez
one())
2012-05-28 12:20:03.224000+01:00
```

why are they not the same with respect to daylight savings? Both should be locale aware, no?

I've read the docs but am none the wiser.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

According to `timezone.now()` [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/_modules/django/utils/timezone/#now):

```
def now():
    """
    Returns an aware or naive datetime.datetime, depending on settings.USE_TZ.
    """
    if settings.USE_TZ:
        # timeit shows that datetime.now(tz=utc) is 24% slower
        return datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    else:
        return datetime.now()
```

It's based on `utc` instead of your default timezone. You could achieve same value by using

```
now = timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(),timezone.get_default_timezone())
print now.astimezone(timezone.utc)
```

Comment: that's somewhat counter-intuitive. I had assumed timezone.now() would have given me now in the default timezone! Not very pythonic in my opinion. Using .astimezone() has fixed my issue, thanks.

Comment: Why do I keep getting a error when I do the following: >>> import datetime
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> from polls.models import Question
>>> # create a Question instance with pub_date 30 days in the future
>>> future_question = Question(pub_date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30))
>>> # was it published recently?
>>> future_question.was_published_recently()
True

Comment: >>> future_question.was_published_recently()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\michmar3\workspace\pollsite\polls\models.py", line 17, in was_p
ublished_recently
    return self.pub_date >= datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\datetime.py", line 1727, in __ge__
    return self.__cmp(other) >= 0
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\datetime.py", line 1765, in _datetime__cmp
    raise TypeError("cannot compare naive and aware datetimes")
TypeError: cannot compare naive and aware datetimes

Comment: @pitchblack408 Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10653144/165603). Try `timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`, in `was_published_recently`.

Comment: @meepmeep That's indeed counterintuitive. At first glance. At second one, you might come to realize that that happens because Django keeps time in UTC until it has to present it to the user. That's where conversion happens. Template tags such as `now` [does](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.1/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1150) this [automatically](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.1/django/template/defaulttags.py#L374).

Answer (score 37):

Since Django 1.11 you can simply call [`django.utils.timezone.localtime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) to fetch `datetime` for your default timezone.

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> timezone.localtime()
```

From docs:

> Converts an aware datetime to a different time zone, by default the current time zone.
>
> When value is omitted, it defaults to [`now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now).
>
> This function doesn’t work on naive datetimes; use [`make_aware()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware) instead.

Comment: This returns May 24, 2019, 1:14 p.m.. Time according to windows is 3:14p.m.

Comment: This does not work for me. It seems to return UTC time..

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a param to `datetime.datetime.now()`:

```
import pytz, datetime
utc = pytz.utc
utc_now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=utc)
```

Or use `timezone`, a la:

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/

Answer (score 5):

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

def now():
    try:
        return timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    except Exception as exp:
        print('TimeZone is not set - {}'.format(exp))
        return datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

If you set `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'` and `USE_TZ = True` in Django setting, it runs the `try` section, otherwise it runs the `except` section.

---

[**NOTE**]:

- `.strftime()` is an option

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

# one can get any time for respective timezone
current_time = datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
print("time in india :", current_time)
```