# Timezone.now() vs datetime.datetime.now()

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-timezone

When should I be using django's `timezone.now()` and when should I be using python's `datetime.datetime.now()`.

For example, in the following `INSERT` which would make more sense?

```
- Product.objects.create(title='Soap', date_added=datetime.datetime.now())
- Product.objects.create(title='Soap', date_added=timezone.now())
```

Is there a rule of thumb on when to use each?

Comment: [Is link this useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783864/django-1-4-timezone-now-vs-datetime-datetime-now)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django 1.4 timezone.now() vs datetime.datetime.now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783864/django-1-4-timezone-now-vs-datetime-datetime-now)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just always use `timezone.now()`.  Django now has timezone support which requires timezone 'aware' datetime objects. `datetime.now()` will return a timezone naive object, whereas `timezone.now()` will return a timezone aware object.

[Read more about Django timezones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/timezones/)

Comment: More precisely, `timezone.now()` will return a naive or aware `datetime` based on the `USE_TZ` setting.

Comment: Could you point me to a resource where I could get to know more about each?

Comment: Sure: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

Comment: That django 1.9 link is broken, so I added a link to the current stable docs

Answer (score 4):

You can write in shell, for example:

```
timezone.datetime.now() < timezone.now()
```

And the error message is:

```
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

They are different objects, only timezone.now() have UTC support

Comment: Can you elaborate on what UTC support means?

Comment: From Django Documentation:
Python’s datetime.datetime objects have a tzinfo attribute that can be used to store time zone information, represented as an instance of a subclass of datetime.tzinfo. When this attribute is set and describes an offset, a datetime object is aware. Otherwise, it’s naive.

Comment: "only timezone.now() have UTC support" means "only timezone.now() have tzinfo attribute"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use UTC, and you're using Python 3.2 or higher, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24666683/28037) says you can do:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
```

This will give you a timezone-aware UTC datetime.