# Django queryset not filtering correctly based on end_date and current_time

Tags: python, html, django, view, model

I'm encountering an issue with my Django project where I have a model Service with an end_date field. I want to filter services based on whether their end_date is in the future, but I'm facing unexpected behavior.

model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from apps.user.models import CustomUser
from apps.location.models import City
from django.utils import timezone


class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Type_of_housing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    areas = models.ManyToManyField(Area,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Service(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type_of_housing = models.ForeignKey(Type_of_housing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    location_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.end_date:
            # Calculate the end date as 14 days from the current date and time
            self.end_date = timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=14)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
class ServiceImage(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='service_images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Image for Service: {self.service.description}"
```

and view.py:

```
def service_list(request):
    current_time = timezone.now()
    print("Current Time:", current_time)

    services = Service.objects.all()
    for service in services:
        print(f"Service {service.title} - end_date: {service.end_date}")

    services = Service.objects.filter(end_date__gt=current_time)

    return render(request, 'service_list.html', {'services': services})
```

Here's a summary of the problem:

I have a Service model with an end_date field that represents the date and time when a service should expire.
I'm using the timezone.now() method to get the current time in UTC timezone.
In my service_list view, I'm trying to filter services where the end_date is greater than the current time to display services that are in the future.
However, some services are not being filtered correctly. Some services with end_date values in the past are still showing, and some services with end_date values in the future are not displaying as expected.
I've checked the following:

My current_time is correctly set in UTC timezone.
The end_date values for services are also in UTC timezone.
I'm using Django's timezone module consistently.
I'm seeking help to understand why this filtering issue is occurring and how to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check timezone.utcnow()
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949959/timezone-now-vs-datetime-datetime-now