# Django saves time data in UTC despite using localtime

Tags: django, datetime

In my settings file, I have :

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

in my views:

```
import datetime

def some_function:
    print(datetime.datetime.now()) << prints my local time
```

However, when using the same `datetime.datetime.now()` to store the current localtime into a DateTimeField, it gets converted in UTC.

I understand that its a good things that it all gets converted into UTC when being stored into Database. Objective being, it will be easier for us to convert UTC to any localtime when we are using these stored values and rendering to the user.

This last step, of converting UTC time to localtime, which I assume that django should do by default, is where I'm stuck at.

the datetime values are still being rendered as UTC instead of my localtime despite using `USE_TZ = True` in my settings.

Comment: So you want to store local date time in the DB right...??

Comment: I want to learn the right way of converting UTC to localtime in Django ( assuming that there is a way to do this in django by default ).

If not store the values in localtime into DB by default

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14661355/10856970) answer might help you. It can be converted using `astimezone` as well from `pytz` module.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49394205/6245650) may help you.