# & operator with datetime. Django

Tags: python, django

I have two dates (datetime), and I would like to make a condition in my view using these dates.

```
      date_start = object.date1
      date_end = object.date2
      now = datetime.datetime.now()

      if now >= date_start & now <=date_end :
            ...
```

I have this error: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'datetime.datetime'. So I tried to add now = now.date(), but still doesn't work.

Any idea on how to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Python uses `and` for boolean and:

```
if now >= date_start and now <= date_end:
    ....
```

It also supports a neat way of testing inequalities:

```
if date_start <= now <= date_end:
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I get this error: "can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes". But I guess it's an other issue.

Comment: @JulietteDupuis: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652819/django-1-4-cant-compare-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes can help you with that.

Comment: Yes indeed! It solved my problem. Thank you again, I'll mark this answer.