# Can't compare naive and aware datetime.now() <= challenge.datetime_end

Tags: python, django, datetime, comparison

I am trying to compare the current date and time with dates and times specified in models using comparison operators:

```
if challenge.datetime_start <= datetime.now() <= challenge.datetime_end:
```

The script errors out with:

```
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

The models look like this:

```
class Fundraising_Challenge(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    datetime_start = models.DateTimeField()
    datetime_end = models.DateTimeField()
```

I also have django using locale date and times.

What I haven't been able to find is the format django uses for DateTimeField().  Is it naive or aware?  And how do I get datetime.now() to recognize locale datetime?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652819/django-1-4-cant-compare-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796008/cant-subtract-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes)

Comment: there is a very nice lib to play with date: pendulum (I am not affiliated)

Answer (score 314, accepted):

By default, the `datetime` object is `naive` in Python, so you need to make both of them either naive or aware `datetime` objects. This can be done using:

```
import datetime
import pytz

utc=pytz.UTC

challenge.datetime_start = utc.localize(challenge.datetime_start) 
challenge.datetime_end = utc.localize(challenge.datetime_end) 
# now both the datetime objects are aware, and you can compare them
```

Note: This would raise a `ValueError` if `tzinfo` is already set. If you are not sure about that, just use

```
start_time = challenge.datetime_start.replace(tzinfo=utc)
end_time = challenge.datetime_end.replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

BTW, you could format a UNIX timestamp in datetime.datetime object with timezone info as following

```
d = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(unix_timestamp))
d_with_tz = datetime.datetime(
    year=d.year,
    month=d.month,
    day=d.day,
    hour=d.hour,
    minute=d.minute,
    second=d.second,
    tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```

Comment: It says: ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set) when it tries to compute: datetimeStart = utc.localize(challenge.datetime_start)

Comment: yep, it raises ValueError.

Comment: Replacing the `tzinfo` doesn't do any conversion, making the comparison incorrect.

Comment: +1 for this. And, using `utc = pytz.utc` to prevent the pylint error
`No value for argument 'dt' in unbound method call (no-value-for-parameter)`.
[pytz link](https://github.com/newvem/pytz/blob/master/pytz/__init__.py#L135)

Comment: You can get `utc` timezone from `datetime`'s `timezone` module. `timezone.utc`.

Comment: Only use the "replace()" method if you already know that both values are in UTC, but *don't* know if they are both offset-aware datetimes. I'm working in a system where a .NET application is passing data to a Python API, and sometimes the .NET datetimes have an offset like "+00:00" and sometimes they don't, but they are still in UTC. Using `datetime.parse()` on a date with the offset creates an offset-aware datetime object in Python, which throws an error if I try to compare it to a `datetime.parse()` on a string without the "+00:00".

Comment: What does _naive_ and _aware_ mean in this context?

Answer (score 172):

`datetime.datetime.now` is not timezone aware.

Django comes with a helper for this, which requires `pytz`

```
from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.now()
```

You should be able to compare `now` to `challenge.datetime_start`

Comment: If `USE_TZ=True` then `timezone.now()` returns a timezone-aware datetime object even if `pytz` is not installed (though it might be recommended to install for other reasons).

Answer (score 136):

### One line of code solution

```
if timezone_aware_var <= datetime.datetime.now(timezone_aware_var.tzinfo):
    pass #some code
```

#### Explained version

```
# Timezone info of your timezone aware variable
timezone = your_timezone_aware_variable.tzinfo

# Current datetime for the timezone of your variable
now_in_timezone = datetime.datetime.now(timezone)

# Now you can do a fair comparison, both datetime variables have the same time zone
if your_timezone_aware_variable <= now_in_timezone:
    pass #some code
```

#### Summary

You must add the timezone info to your `now()` datetime.
However, you must add the **same** timezone of the reference variable; that is why I first read the `tzinfo` attribute.

Comment: This seems like the most logical approach - thanks!

Comment: Naive solution. Logical solution. this should solution should be the top answer.

Answer (score 57):

Disable time zone.
Use `challenge.datetime_start.replace(tzinfo=None);`

You can also use `replace(tzinfo=None)` for other **datetime**.

```
if challenge.datetime_start.replace(tzinfo=None) <= datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=None) <= challenge.datetime_end.replace(tzinfo=None):
```

Answer (score 15):

no third-party, only the native datetime module.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

time1 = datetime.strptime('2021-07-15T00:22:02+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
time2 = datetime(2021, 7, 15, tzinfo=timezone(offset=timedelta()))
if time1 < time2:
    print(True)
```

Comment: How would you make this work with datetime.now()?

Comment: +many for no-third party libs required!!

Comment: @jtlz2, you'd use `datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=timezone(offset=timedelta()))`

Answer (score 8):

To make your datetime object timezone aware from naive, simply add the function:

```
datetimeObject.astimezone()
```

Answer (score 4):

It is working form me.
Here I am geeting the table created datetime and adding 10  minutes on the datetime.
later depending on the current time, Expiry Operations are done.

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
import pytz
```

Added 10 minutes on database datetime

table_datetime = '2019-06-13 07:49:02.832969' (example)

```
# Added 10 minutes on database datetime
# table_datetime = '2019-06-13 07:49:02.832969' (example)

table_expire_datetime = table_datetime + timedelta(minutes=10 )

# Current datetime
current_datetime = datetime.now()


# replace the timezone in both time
expired_on = table_expire_datetime.replace(tzinfo=utc)
checked_on = current_datetime.replace(tzinfo=utc)


if expired_on < checked_on:
    print("Time Crossed)
else:
    print("Time not crossed ")
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set the timezone for date_time which already has a timezone.
Use `replace` and `astimezone` functions.

```
local_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

current_time = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_tz)
```

Answer (score 1):

So the way I would solve this problem is to make sure the two datetimes are in the right timezone.

I can see that you are using `datetime.now()` which will return the systems current time, with no tzinfo set.

tzinfo is the information attached to a datetime to let it know what timezone it is in. If you are using naive datetime you need to be consistent through out your system. I would highly recommend only using `datetime.utcnow()`

seeing as somewhere your are creating datetime that have tzinfo associated with them, what you need to do is make sure those are localized (has tzinfo associated) to the correct timezone.

Take a look at [Delorean](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), it makes dealing with this sort of thing much easier.

Comment: You also see this issue with utcnow.

Comment: Seconded. `utcnow` won't add timezone info

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SQLAlchemy` and storing the [DateTime](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html?highlight=datetime#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime) then you can store it with timezone info. This will allow you to compare that DateTime with timezone-aware DateTimes. Example Column definition in `SQLAlchemy core`:

```py
Column("created_at", DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.6 and newer, you can leverage the native `datetime` capability.

```py
utc_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0, datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example for an actual date to see what the input should look like?
Seems clearer to provide the `tzinfo` in the `datetime` method.

Comment: Sure, you can find the examples in the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat

Answer (score 1):

**[Option 1]** To make both objects `datetime` aware

**Sample code :**

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
# If `challenge_datetime_end` is already timezone-aware, ensure `now()` is also aware
now_aware = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

# Now you can safely compare `now_aware` with `challenge_datetime_end`
if now_aware < challenge_datetime_end:
   # Your logic here
```

**[Option 2]** To make both objects `datetime` naive

**Sample code :**

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
# Assuming `challenge_datetime_end` is timezone-aware
challenge_datetime_end_naive = challenge_datetime_end.replace(tzinfo=None)
    
# Now you can compare it with the naive `datetime.now()`
if datetime.now() < challenge_datetime_end_naive:
# Your logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have controlled the time zone with pytz and I have converted the date to native with  timezone from django.utils:

```
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone

def _my_method(native_date, timezone):
    aware_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(timezone))
    return timezone.make_naive(aware_date) >  native_date
```

Also you can make aware the native date with timezone.make_aware

Answer (score 0):

From time to time this error pops up in my notebooks... I have no clue why.

My datetime objects are usually in arrays. I tried some of the answers above, but the way I found to deal with this problem is

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

array_with_datetime = np.array( 
                          mdates.num2date( 
                                     mdates.date2num( 
                                                 array_with_datetime)))
```

not elegant, but it works. If I not use the `np.array`, it returns a list.

Answer (score -2):

Just:

```
dt = datetimeObject.strftime(format) # format = your datetime format ex) '%Y %d %m'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt,format)
```

So do this:

```
start_time = challenge.datetime_start.strftime('%Y %d %m %H %M %S')
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time,'%Y %d %m %H %M %S')

end_time = challenge.datetime_end.strftime('%Y %d %m %H %M %S')
end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time,'%Y %d %m %H %M %S')
```

and then use `start_time` and `end_time`