# Python date match with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following code:

```
fixtures = StraightredFixture.objects.filter(soccerseason=soccerseason,fixturematchday=fixturematchday).order_by('fixturedate')

firstGameTime = str(fixtures[0].fixturedate).split()
currentTime = str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).split()


if firstGameTime >= currentTime:
    selectteams = True
else:
    selectteams = False
```

Whatever the date of the firstGameTime is it always returns False.  Two examples are as follows:

```
firstGameTime  = ['2010-10-28', '11:30:00+00:00'] 
currentTime = ['2016-10-29', '10:51:50']
selectteams = False

firstGameTime = ['2010-10-30', '11:30:00+00:00'] 
currentTime = ['2016-10-29', '10:53:16']
selectteams = False
```

In the second example I would expect it to say True as the firstGameTime is the 30th whereas the currentTime is the 29th.

I have a feeling it is to do with the +00:00 part but am at a loss on how to fix this.  Any help would be appreciated, many thanks, Alan.

Comment: Why are you converting these to lists of strings for comparison, rather than keeping them as datetimes?

Comment: Read it online somewhere as a solution. I don't need to, so any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datetimes are directly comparable. There is no need to convert to lists of strings.

```
firstGameTime = fixtures[0].fixturedate
currentTime = datetime.now()

if firstGameTime >= currentTime:
    ...
```

However, since this is Django you could do this directly in the query:

```
selectteams = StraightredFixture.objects.filter(
    soccerseason=soccerseason,
    fixturematchday=fixturematchday
    fixturedate__gte=datetime.now()
).exists()
```

Comment: Sadly I am getting the following error: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes.

Comment: By using your answer and that help at the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307623/cant-compare-naive-and-aware-datetime-now-challenge-datetime-end I got the solution. Many thanks for your help.  Could the person who downvoted me the question contact me and help me understand the downvote for future reference.