# Comparing two datetime strings

Tags: python, python-datetime, datetime-comparison

I have two DateTime strings. How would I compare them and tell which comes first?

```
A = '2019-02-12 15:01:45:145'
B = '2019-02-12 15:02:02:22'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483420/python-how-to-compare-two-date-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both the date/time strings are in ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) you can compare them with a simple string compare, like this:

```
a = '2019-02-12 15:01:45.145'
b = '2019-02-12 15:02:02.022'

if a < b:
    print('Time a comes before b.')
else:
    print('Time a does not come before b.')
```

Your strings, however, have an extra ':' after which come... milliseconds?  I'm not sure.  But if you convert them to a standard hh:mm:ss.xxx... form, then your date strings will be naturally comparable.

---

If there is no way to change the fact that you're receiving those strings in `hh:mm:ss:xx` format (I'm assuming that `xx` is milliseconds, but only you can say for sure), then you can "munge" the string slightly by parsing out the final ":xx" and re-attaching it as ".xxx", like this:

```
def mungeTimeString(timeString):
    """Converts a time string in "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:xx" format
       to a time string in "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.xxx" format."""
    head, _, tail = timeString.rpartition(':')
    return '{}.{:03d}'.format(head, int(tail))
```

Then call it with:

```
a = '2019-02-12 15:01:45:145'
b = '2019-02-12 15:02:02:22'

a = mungeTimeString(a)
b = mungeTimeString(b)

if a < b:
    print('Time a comes before b.')
else:
    print('Time a does not come before b.')
```

Comment: Let's assume (it's not an assumption if we look at the question, `A = '...`) they are not already in proper format and provide an answer with the part that takes care of converting them to that (let's say from character strings to datetime). (p.s. I am holding back myself to not downvote but others may not do so). Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

This format has milliseconds in it, so it cannot be parsed by `time.strptime`. I chose to split according to the last colon, parse the left part, and manually convert the right part, add them together.

```
A = '2019-02-12 15:01:45:145'
B = '2019-02-12 15:02:02:22'

import time

def parse_date(s):
    date,millis = s.rsplit(":",1)
    return time.mktime(time.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + int(millis)/1000.0

print(parse_date(A))
print(parse_date(B))
```

prints:

```
1549958505.145
1549958522.022
```

now compare the results instead of printing them to get what you want

If your convention on milliseconds is different (ex: here `22` could also mean `220`), then it's slightly different. Pad with zeroes on the right, then parse:

```
def parse_date(s):
    date,millis = s.rsplit(":",1)
    millis = millis+"0"*(3-len(millis))   # pad with zeroes
    return time.mktime(time.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + int(millis)/1000.0
```

in that case the result it:

```
1549958505.145
1549958522.22
```