# Django - Suspending/deactivating an account for N amount of seconds

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In my Django application, If the user enters the wrong password more than 7 times, then I want to suspend/deactivate their account for 10 seconds.

I perform an If statement to see if the wrong password has been inputted more than 7 times, and that works fine.

Inside the if statement, I want to set **user.is_active** to **False** for 10 seconds so they cannot login. After 10 seconds has passed, I want **user.is_active** to be set back to **True** so they can attempt to login again.

How would I implement this functionality? Thank you.

Update -
views.py:

```
if user.active_after > current:
                    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Yes! Not locked'}, status=200)
```

models.py

```
active_after = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Error I receive:
**TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes**

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The obvious way is to put `sleep(10)` in the code.  If that isn't what you want, please elaborate.

Comment: @JohnGordon Django could be deployed under a parallel request handler system. In that case, let say, if user try another password in another tab simultaneously, server test that password since user profile is not deactivated properly!

Comment: @aminrd I was hoping to gently prompt the OP to consider issues just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to preventing user in Front-end (i.e. using javascript, ....). If you want to add in backend as well, you can add `datetime` field such as `user.active_after` which each model should only be active after that time.

Then when you got a wrong password, you can change that field to:

```
current =  datetime.datetime.now()

# add 10 seconds to current time
user.active_after = current + datetime.timedelta(0,10)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. How would you implement the functionality where a user can only be active after the **user.active_after** time.

Comment: @eweee You can check the current time before doing anything ( e.g. checking another password try). If that time is less than ‘active_after’ stop doing it. Otherwise, you realize the user is active.

Comment: I attempt to add the functionality you requested, however I keep encountering this error. Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: @eweee Well, that's a different story. You can find the answer to new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307623/cant-compare-naive-and-aware-datetime-now-challenge-datetime-end/15307743

Comment: Thank you for all the support you have given. I am now on the right tracks.