# DateTime from Database (SqlAlchemy) not same timestamp like pendulum parsed date

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, pendulum

I have pendulum parsed a date string:

```py
pendulum.parse('2015-03-09')
```

This object is now stored to a SqlAlchemy database table (mysql) with `Column(SqlAlchemy.DateTime)`

Now, I load this column value, its then:

[image]

Now I want to compare it back with the string date ... like this:

```py
created.timestamp() == pendulum.parse('2015-03-09').timestamp()
```

which results in `False` ... WHAT!?

```py
created.timestamp() -> 1425855600.0
pendulum.parse('2015-03-09').timestamp() -> 1425859200.0
```

Here is the pendulum parsed object FYI:

[image]

So why are the timestamps different?

Comment: At a _guess_, because the pendulum timestamp  is time zone aware, but the other is not.  Note that the difference between the two is 3600 -> one hour.

Comment: Okay, got it, but how to solve this? any idea?

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843203/how-to-store-a-datetime-in-mysql-with-timezone-info) may help you.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the database column

Comment: Then you need to make the objects comparable - perhaps the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307623/cant-compare-naive-and-aware-datetime-now-challenge-datetime-end) may help.