# Trying BranchDateTimeOperator in Airflow, But getting Naive Aware datetime issue

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, astronomer

I am trying to use BranchDatetimeOperator in Airflow, for a special use case. But I am getting error.

```
cond3 = BranchDateTimeOperator(
task_id="datetime_branch",
follow_task_ids_if_true=["sample_pybq1"],
follow_task_ids_if_false=["sample_pybq12"],
target_upper=pendulum.datetime(2023, 6, 21, 20, 0, 0),
target_lower=pendulum.datetime(2023, 6, 21, 13, 0, 0),
dag=new_dag,
)

cond3 >> [sample_pybq1, sample_pybq12] >> sample_bq_task
```

If cond3 satisfies, I would to call sample_pybq1 if not sample_pybq12 and then sample_bq_task in either case.

But I am getting this error.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/datetime.py", line 87, in choose_branch
if upper is not None and upper < now:
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

Comment: what is your airflow version ?

Comment: try to add .astimezone() to upper and lower dates

Comment: Airflow version 2.3.2

Comment: Also, if you could see that error has been prompted when

    if upper is not None and upper < now:
    TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307623/cant-compare-naive-and-aware-datetime-now-challenge-datetime-end. might help

Comment: I tried.. No luck, ozs